# Package pgf Error: No shape named A known

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, errors, compilation-error

I am trying to draw a 2-coloured graph, but my code does not compile. Interestingly enough, I had no problems with it until I used the babel package to change my document's language.

Here is my code:

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph[circular placement, radius=2cm,
             empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}, edges={dashed}] {
        \foreach \x in {A,...,F} {
          \foreach \y in {\x,...,F} {
            \x -- \y;
          };
        };
      };
      \foreach \x [count=\idx from 0] in {A,...,F} {
        \pgfmathparse{90 + \idx * (360 / 6)}
        \node at (\pgfmathresult:2.5cm) {\x};
      };
      \draw (A) edge[red, thick] node[black] {} (D);
      \draw (A) edge[red, thick] node[black] {} (C);
      \draw (A) edge[red, thick] node[black] {} (E);
      \draw (A) edge[blue, thick] node[black] {} (B);
      \draw (A) edge[blue, thick] node[black] {} (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I appreciate any help!

Edit: the full code with used packages:

```
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, lmodern}
    \usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{bbold}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usepackage{epigraph}
    \usepackage{caption} 
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{blkarray}
    \usepackage[czech]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
       \begin{tikzpicture}
          \graph[circular placement, radius=2cm,
                 empty nodes, nodes={circle,draw}, edges={dashed}] {
            \foreach \x in {A,...,F} {
              \foreach \y in {\x,...,F} {
                \x -- \y;
              };
            };
          };
          \foreach \x [count=\idx from 0] in {A,...,F} {
            \pgfmathparse{90 + \idx * (360 / 6)}
            \node at (\pgfmathresult:2.5cm) {\x};
          };
          \draw (A) edge[red, thick] node[black] {} (D);
          \draw (A) edge[red, thick] node[black] {} (C);
          \draw (A) edge[red, thick] node[black] {} (E);
          \draw (A) edge[blue, thick] node[black] {} (B);
          \draw (A) edge[blue, thick] node[black] {} (F);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you load `\usetikzlibrary{graphs}` in your preamble? I get no errors when I load Ti*k*Z and the `graphs` library. Please post your preamble or a compilable example (including `\documentclass` etc.).

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable example showing the problem. LaTeX behavior depends a *lot* on the preamble... (If the problem is really babel, try adding `shorthands=off` in the options... But given that you don't even say *which* language you switched to...

Comment: Where do you think are the names of the nodes defined? The names of nodes are usually defined like so: \node (A) at (0,0) {node A};

Comment: Thank you. I tried loading the graphs package but it did not do anything, unfortunately. I switched to Czech language - if I may ask, how exactly do I add the shorthands off?

Comment: add ` \usetikzlibrary{babel}` to your preamble